# Is there a clean way to animate the value of a readonly DependencyProperty?

Tags: wpf, animation, wpf-controls, dependency-properties

I have a control where I want to animate the value of a readonly `DependencyProperty`

Using vanilla animation like this does not work (**as expected**):

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation(value, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
this.BeginAnimation(SomeValueProperty, animation);
```

Guess I'm looking for something like:

```
var animation = new DoubleAnimation(value, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
this.BeginAnimation(SomeValuePropertyKey, animation);
```

Is there a clean way to animate my property using the framework?

Comment: Even if you would pass `SomeValueProperty.DependencyProperty` to BeginAnimation, it would give you a runtime exception, as  DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly sets `IsAnimationProhibited = true` on the property metadata.

Comment: Yes, it would not make sense if the dp of a readonly dp could be changed from the outside. 
An overload for BeginAnimation that takes a DependencyPropertyKey would be nice. I ran out of ideas so I asked this question.
Don't feel like rolling my own animation.

Answer (score 2):

Found a ~clever~ solution:

```
public class DummyControl : Control
{
    internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey SomePropPropertyKey = DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly(
        "SomeProp",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(DummyControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0));

    // A proxy that is used for animating. Sets the value of the readonly property on change.
    private static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropProxyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "SomePropProxy",
        typeof(double),
        typeof(DummyControl),
        new PropertyMetadata(0.0, OnSomePropProxyChanged));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SomePropProperty = SomePropPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;

    public double SomeProp
    {
        get { return (double)this.GetValue(SomePropProperty); }
        protected set { this.SetValue(SomePropPropertyKey, value); }
    }

    public void AnimateTo(double value)
    {
        var animation = new DoubleAnimation(value, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));
        this.BeginAnimation(SomePropProxyProperty, animation);
        // We are animating the proxy here.
    }

    private static void OnSomePropProxyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        d.SetValue(SomePropPropertyKey, e.NewValue);
        // Updating the value of the readonly property here.
    }
}
```

This does not feel like a very clean solution but it uses standard animation at least. Please suggest something better!

Comment: Unfortuantly in this way you break the purpouse of a readonly property by exposing a clear way to set this property outside of the control.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing a proxy property is one solution but the drowback is that this brakes useless the readonly restriction. A slightly better way is to create a proxy object. This will make the animated property only accessible inside the control you are writing.

```
public class AnimationProxy<T> : Animatable
{

    private Action<T> _valueUpdateCallback;

    #region AnimatableProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty AnimatablePropertyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AnimatableProperty", typeof(T), typeof(AnimationProxy<T>),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(T),
                new PropertyChangedCallback(OnAnimatablePropertyChanged)));

    public T AnimatableProperty
    {
        get { return (T)GetValue(AnimatablePropertyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AnimatablePropertyProperty, value); }
    }

    private static void OnAnimatablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        AnimationProxy<T> target = (AnimationProxy<T>)d;
        T oldAnimatableProperty = (T)e.OldValue;
        T newAnimatableProperty = target.AnimatableProperty;
        target.OnAnimatablePropertyChanged(oldAnimatableProperty, newAnimatableProperty);
    }

    protected virtual void OnAnimatablePropertyChanged(T oldAnimatableProperty, T newAnimatableProperty)
    {
        _valueUpdateCallback?.Invoke(newAnimatableProperty);
    }

    #endregion


    public AnimationProxy(Action<T> valueUpdateCallback)
    {
        _valueUpdateCallback = valueUpdateCallback;
    }

    //Override to keep compiler happy
    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

So now to animate the readonly property all you need is to provide the callback and animate the proxy object:

```
var animationProxy = new AnimationProxy<double>(SetReadOnlyProperty);
animationProxy.AnimatableProperty = ReadOnlyProperty;
var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, new Duration(CurrentTimeLeft));
animationProxy.BeginAnimation(AnimationProxy<double>.AnimatablePropertyProperty, animation);
```